# Create Zip of all files in a subfolder with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I'm trying to create a batch script which is creating a .zip file including all files of a subfolder and which is named with the name of each subfolder.

If already tried to work with `/f %%F` but nothing seems to work. My currently working code looks like this:

```
for /d %%X in (*.*) do "C:\7zip\7za" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

which is giving me the correct named .zip file but without taking the files out of the subfolder so that my files look like this:

```
example.zip
-- example
---- example1.txt
---- example2.txt
```

I am thankful for any help. It feels like theres not too much to make it work like i need it!

Comment: Try either `for /D %%X in (*.*) do "C:\7zip\7za" a "%%X.zip" "%%~X\*.*"` or `for /D %%X in (*.*) do pushd "%%~X" && ("C:\7zip\7za" a "..\%%~X.zip" "*.*" & popd)`...

Comment: Thank you so much. Your second script does it for me!

Comment: Do you further have any idea how to exclude specific files like *.db from the process?

Comment: Ok, got it `-x!*.db` is the way to go. So my final working script looks like this `for /D %%X in (*.*) do pushd "%%~X" && ("C:\7zip\7za" -x!*.db a "..\%%~X.zip" "*.*" & popd)`

Comment: Perfect! You just need to replace in the `7za` command line the `*.*` with `*` to really process all files (sorry, was my mistake!)...